# JavaScript files.length not working in ie9 need alternative approach

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have the following JavaScript function which is failing in internet explorer 9 on the line which declares the variable `filesattached`.

```
function VesselDetails() {      

    insurancestart = $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_datetimepickerinsstart').val();
    insuranceend = $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_datetimepickerinsend').val();
    filesattached = $("input:File")[0].files.length;  

    //set up JS objects
    $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_datetimepickerinsend').datetimepicker({ format: 'd/m/Y H:i a' });
    $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_datetimepickerinsstart').datetimepicker({ format: 'd/m/Y H:i a' });

    //subscribe to change events
    $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_datetimepickerinsstart').change(function () {
        insurancestart = $("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_datetimepickerinsstart").val();
    });

    $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_datetimepickerinsend').change(function () {
        insuranceend = $("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_datetimepickerinsend").val();
    });

    $("input:File").change(function () {
        filesattached = $("input:File")[0].files.length;
    });

    ins_client();
}
```

The `ins_client` method looks like this:

```
function ins_client(sender, e) {
    if (pagemode == 'EditVessel') {
        e.IsValid = true;
    }

    if (pagemode == 'NewVessel') {
        if (insurancestart !== '' && insuranceend !== '' && filesattached > 0) {
            e.IsValid = true;
        }
        else {
            e.IsValid = false;
        }
    }
}
```

This all works perfectly well in chrome and ie 11 but the length property is returning an undefined for ie 9. I am using the length because I only want the page to be valid for a new vessel request once a document has been submitted, is there another way of doing this which will work in ie 9 onwards and chrome, apologies if this has already been answered elsewhere but I cannot find a workaround anywhere that enables this to continue working in the same way but in ie9 onwards and chrome.

Comment: Since IE9 doesn't support it. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7139244/html5-how-to-count-the-length-of-the-files-from-the-multiple-input-field

Comment: All these answers mention the length property?

Comment: Check the comment on the accepted answer.

Comment: So if IE9 doesnt support it why would this be helpful to me?

Comment: Isn't it helpful to know the road is closed ahead and one should be taking u-turn?

Comment: I know that approach is not possible, which is why I was asking if there was a way of refactoring what I have to approach the problem in a different manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replaced:

```
filesattached = $("input:File")[0].files.length;
```

With:

```
var areFilesAttached = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_fuAttachment').value ? true : false;
```

Within the `VesselDetails` function.

Then replaced the `if` statement within `ins_client` with the following:

```
if (pagemode == 'NewVessel') {
        if (insurancestart !== '' && insuranceend !== '' && areFilesAttached == true) {
            e.IsValid = true;
        }
        else {
            e.IsValid = false;
        }
    }
```

This was an alternative approach which enabled me to check whether or not a file had been provided without using the `files.length` property which is not compatible with `IE9`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this can't be achieved, IE9 does not support HTML5 File API and therefore it returns undefined value for files property.

Take a look at [**FILE API**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi)