# limit maximum item on multiple file upload parsley validation

Tags: jquery, validation, parsley.js, parsley

I want it to validate. If user selects more than 5 files than it should show a warning

```
<input max-file-input="5" id="fileinput" type="file" multiple="multiple" name="files[]" accept="image/*"  data-classbutton="btn btn-default" data-classinput="form-control inline" class="filestyle form-control">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no builtin validator to do that, but you should be able to write your own easily.

Pointers:

- [HTML5: How to count the length of the files from the multiple-input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7139244/html5-how-to-count-the-length-of-the-files-from-the-multiple-input-field)
- Last two comments of https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/issues/989

Comment: can you tell me how can i make a JS or J query function, that should check on change of fileinput if it is not grater than 5 ?